# Laravel is adding some "\n" to query builder

Tags: laravel, mariadb, laravel-query-builder

I'm in MariaDB 5.6, Laravel 5.4.

I have a query builder like this:

```
DB::select( DB::raw("
    INSERT INTO rgl_ejer_por_comunas (
        com_id, 
        sum 
    )
    VALUES (
        $com,
        $sum
    ) 
"));
```

It was working fine for weeks, now I don't know why Laravel is adding some "\n" at the end of each line so it's giving me now this error:

```
#message: """
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '\n ◀
                    0.28152777777778,\n
                    0.28152777777778,\n
   ' at line 17 (SQL: \n
            INSERT INTO rgl_ejer_por_comunas (\n
                comuna_id, \n
                sum \n
            )\n
            VALUES (\n
                15101,\n
                20.27\n
            )
"""
#code: "42000"
```

What could have happened?

Comment: Be **extremely careful** when using raw queries. You're injecting values into your SQL there without any apparent escaping which creates a potential [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/). [`selectRaw`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions) supports placeholder values, so you can avoid doing this the ugly `$com` type way.

Comment: @tadman i think your comment is the answer and wondering why are you using it as a comment

Comment: It could be that `raw` is getting overly concerned about newlines, but it's not intended to run on multi-line queries. This will properly escape multi-line *values*. Is there any reason you can't do this with `DB::table('rgl_ejer_por_comunas)->insert(['comuna_id' => 1501, 'sum' => 20.27 ])`?

Comment: @UXLabs I'm not sure if that solves any problems. I just flag questions like this so people don't have their sites cracked wide open.

Comment: @tadman ok, I will try that way, but I still don't get it why I'm getting this error now after several weeks working all fine.

Comment: Well, it works of course with `insert()` but I still don't know the original question

Comment: Did you patch or update something? Did you format your code differently? Something changed even if you don't know precisely what.

Comment: I changed some lines before that code, but only some vars and stuff, no more than that. Now it's working all fine. Weird because I have many more `DB::select(DB::raw("` after the one who was giving me problems, so I don't know what happened with it.